# How to calculate Total Amount by Change Status Debit or Credit from array in components in Vue3 JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

I have one Amount column in my table and I want to calculate total debit, total credit, total remaining amount by chnage in status of dropdown debit and credit.
if dropdown selection is debit then "Remaining=Amount-current Amount" and
if dropdown selection is credit then add amount in remaining balance, This Is My Code.  **Please help I'm new in Vuejs**

```
<script>
import Breadcrumb from "primevue/breadcrumb";
import Button from "primevue/button";
import InputText from "primevue/inputtext";
import Calendar from "primevue/calendar";
import Dropdown from "primevue/dropdown";
import InputNumber from "primevue/inputnumber";
import { ref, reactive } from "vue";
import { computed } from "@vue/reactivity";

export default {
  name: "CashPayementVoucher",
  components: {
    Button,
    InputText,
    Calendar,
    Dropdown,
    InputNumber,
    Breadcrumb,
  },
  setup() {
    const home = ref({ icon: "pi pi-home", to: "/" });
    const items = ref([
      { label: "Vouchers" },
      { label: "Cash Payement Voucher" },
    ]);
    const accountsData = ref([
      { name: "0987-12345678-1", value: "0987-12345678-1" },
      { name: "0987-12345678-2", value: "0987-12345678-2" },
      { name: "0987-12345678-3", value: "0987-12345678-3" },
      { name: "0987-12345678-4", value: "0987-12345678-4" },
      { name: "0987-12345678-5", value: "0987-12345678-5" },
    ]);
    const projectsData = ref([
      { name: "Blue World City", value: "Blue World City" },
      { name: "Estate 92", value: "Estate 92" },
      { name: "Atlantics City", value: "Atlantics City" },
      { name: "Park View City", value: "Park View City" },
      { name: "Bahria Town", value: "Bahria Town" },
    ]);
    const usersData = ref([
      { name: "Ali Suleman", value: "Ali Suleman" },
      { name: "Muhammad Khan", value: "Muhammad Khan" },
      { name: "Sheraz Ahemad", value: "Sheraz Ahemad" },
      { name: "Mehbob Sultan", value: "Mehboob Sultan" },
      { name: "Usama Javeed", value: "Usama javeed" },
      { name: "Shoaib Khan", value: "Shoaib Khang" },
    ]);
    const payementType = ref([
      { name: "Debit", value: 1 },
      { name: "Credit", value: 0 },
    ]);
    const invoice = reactive({
      account: "",
      date: "",
      projects: "",
      payeeName: "",
      amount: 0,
      details: [
        {
          account: "",
          name: "",
          description: "",
          debit_credit: 1,
          amount: 0,
        },
      ],
      totalCredit: 0,
      totalDebit: 0,
      difference: 0,
    });
    const addnewRow = () => {
      invoice.details.push({
        account: "",
        name: "",
        description: "",
        debit_credit: "",
        amount: 0,
      });
    };
    const removeRow = (index) => {
      invoice.details.splice(index, 1);
    };
    const postData = () => {
      console.log("Hello I'm Here 'Cash Payement Voucher'", invoice);
    };
    
    const remaining =computed(() => {
      return (
        invoice.amount +
        invoice.details.reduce(function (prevTotal, detail) {
          let temp = detail.debit_credit > 0 ? detail.amount * -1 : detail.amount * 1;
          return +prevTotal + temp;
        }, 0)
      );
    });

    return {
      home,
      items,
      accountsData,
      projectsData,
      usersData,
      payementType,
      invoice,
      addnewRow,
      removeRow,
      postData,
      remaining
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Image Link**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkdOZ.png

Comment: Please edit your question to include the images direct to it (can be done using `![image text](img location)`) - you also seem to be trying to add 2 images, which are the exact same, please use a single image once (and if required), adding more if needed

Answer (score 0):

Please on the next question insert only important code for your problem it's easier to analyze code. To solve your problem create computed property which will return data depending on dropdown choose.

```
computed() {
   calculateValue() {
     if (this.details[0].debit_credit === 'Debit') {
        return //enter your equation for debit option i can't find currentAmount data
     else if (this.details[0].debit_credit === 'Credit') {
        return //enter your equation for credit option
    }
     return null
  }
 }
}
```

Then you can display calculateValue anywhere in HTML code:

```
 <template>
    <div> Balance: {{calculateValue}} </div>
 </template>
```

Comment: Hi youngman please review agian my code  and see a picture atteched with post